# Office Js addin to export sheet in selected workbook

Tags: javascript, excel, vba, office-addins

I am tryng to create an Office JS Addin, where I can choose a file from input form and then the ActiveSheet will be moved to that workbook and saved.

I can do this using VBA and VSTO Addins, but I am not able to find a solution using a JS Addin? Any source or help on this part?

Comment: Welcome navendu! Please take some time to read the introduction to Stack Overflow and earn your first badge. We're a little bit different from other sites. Here's how...  https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: What have you tried? Please show your code.